# How to add “Variation” product meta tab to custom product type

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm developing a theme with WooCommerce.

Wanted to enable "variation" tab for my custom product type but have no idea how to do it.

Here is the sample screenshot for reference:
[image: Here is the sample screenshot for reference]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know myself, but Variable products are set up differently from Simple products. If you've set up your custom product based on either the Simple product model or the Abstract product model, it probably won't account for the changes needed for variations.

Have a look at the Variable product object and see how it differs from a Simple one.